# How to read test data from a JSON file in Cypress using cy.readfile() and make it available in the test

Tags: cypress, readfile

My test set up is :

1. I've all the reusable functions as commands in commands.js file.
2. My test are available Under integration folder.

I used cy.fixtures initially to load my test data. Then i found out that the data is not cleared from memory even after the test ends. It's a known issue.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4716

So i changed my approach to reading the data from a JSON file using cy.readfile() before my tests ie before it statement
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/eoicorporate.json')
.then(testData=>testData[type]=json);

However I get below error when i try to run my test.

ReferenceError
testData is not defined

Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: EOI login

Comment: There's some things not clear in your post, for example the error message does not fit with the `cy.readFile()` line. Please post the whole test, or if it's very long then post more of the test from the top of the spec file. There could be a couple of things causing the problem.

Comment: it('Submit Corporare EOI', () => {
      
      cy.visit(testData.url);
    cy.contains('Start').click();
});








This is the test code. It's written assuming read file reads the content of the files and assigns the value of returned object to testData.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.